# Android SQLite Table not created

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to create a table of statistics but for some reason, it doesn't create until I call `StatisticsAdapter.insertEntry()` for the first time. After that, I can delete that code, reload a new version, and then everything works fine. Since that's not going to work in real life, I was wondering how can you create an empty table?

Currently there is an error at the `if(StatisticsAdapter.getCount(isbn) < 1)` because it says there is no such table. Why is that happening?

**Main Code**

```
StatisticsAdapter=new StatisticsAdapter(this);
    StatisticsAdapter=StatisticsAdapter.open();
    Calendar curDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    if(StatisticsAdapter.getCount(isbn) < 1)
        StatisticsAdapter.insertEntry(isbn, curDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), (curDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1), 1);
    else
        StatisticsAdapter.increaseCount(isbn);
```

**StatisticsAdapter**

```
public class StatisticsAdapter {
public static final int NAME_COLUMN = 1;
static final String tableName="STATISTICS";
// TODO: Create public field for each column in your table.
// SQL Statement to create a new database.
public static final String STATISTICS_TABLE_CREATE = "create table "+"STATISTICS"
        + "( " +"ID"+" integer primary key autoincrement,"
        + "ISBN text,"
        + "YEAR text,"
        + "MONTH text,"
        + "COUNT integer); ";
// Variable to hold the database instance
public  SQLiteDatabase db;
// Context of the application using the database.
private final Context context;
// Database open/upgrade helper
private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
public  StatisticsAdapter(Context _context) 
{
    context = _context;
    dbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
}
public  StatisticsAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close() 
{
    db.close();
}

public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
{
    return db;
}

public void insertEntry(String ISBN, int year, int month, int count)
{
   ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    // Assign values for each row.
    newValues.put("ISBN", ISBN);
    newValues.put("YEAR", ((Integer)year).toString());
    if(month>=10)
        newValues.put("MONTH", ((Integer)month).toString());
    else
        newValues.put("MONTH", "0"+((Integer)month).toString());
    newValues.put("COUNT", count);

    // Insert the row into your table
    db.insert("STATISTICS", null, newValues);
    ///Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public int getCount(String ISBN)
    {
        //Query
        String query = "select COUNT from STATISTICS where ISBN = ?";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {ISBN});
        if(cursor.getCount()<1) // title Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return 0;
        }
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("COUNT"));
        cursor.close();
        return count;               
    }
```

**DataBaseHelper**

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{   
    // Database Version
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";

    // ============================ End Variables ===========================

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) 
    {
               super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Called when no database exists in disk and the helper class needs
    // to create a new one.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) 
    {
            _db.execSQL(LoginDataBaseAdapter.USER_TABLE_CREATE);
            _db.execSQL(CheckOutDataBaseAdapter.CHECKOUT_TABLE_CREATE);
            _db.execSQL(InventoryAdapter.INVENTORY_TABLE_CREATE);
            _db.execSQL(StatisticsAdapter.STATISTICS_TABLE_CREATE);
    }
    // Called when there is a database version mismatch meaning that the version
    // of the database on disk needs to be upgraded to the current version.
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion) 
    {
            // Log the version upgrade.
            Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " +_oldVersion + " to " +_newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");


            // Upgrade the existing database to conform to the new version. Multiple
            // previous versions can be handled by comparing _oldVersion and _newVersion
            // values.
            // on upgrade drop older tables
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + LoginDataBaseAdapter.USER_TABLE_CREATE);
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CheckOutDataBaseAdapter.CHECKOUT_TABLE_CREATE);
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + InventoryAdapter.INVENTORY_TABLE_CREATE);
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + StatisticsAdapter.STATISTICS_TABLE_CREATE);

            // Create a new one.
            onCreate(_db);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

try to extend `SQLiteOpenHelper`

override

```
@Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }
```

The database is not actually created or opened until one of `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()` is called.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean? I thought I already did that override in the DataBaseHelper. How and where would I call `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()` ?

Comment: As I mentioned above, you are missing the onCreate method from your DataBaseHelper class.  The STATISTICS_TABLE_CREATE also needs to be moved to the DataBaseHelper class.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried uninstalling the app before running the code? If the previous version of your code created db without statistics table, you have to increment your database version (DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_VERSION) to trigger onUpgrade call, which will create the table.

The second thing you can try is to extract table name into constant and using it instead hardcoded strings. Maybe you have a typo somewhere?

I'd also recommend pulling the database from device and checking its schema with command line sqlite client:

```
adb shell
busybox cp data/data/com.your.package/databases/database.db /sdcard
exit
adb pull /sdcard/database.db
sqlite3 database.db
.schema
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Class `DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper`

and override like below:

```
// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = Crate table query;
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}
```

Now, you want to called  `SQLiteDatabase db = cintext.getWritableDatabase();` from your `Activity` for accessing Database table.

Comment: I did that, but I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: @erad also you're query is wrong here. "ID integer primary key autoincrement". No need to declare autoincrement. A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will auto-increment in SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

This Problem has been happened when the app on device is lower version and you changing database (Add table, Create new DB, ...) and you install new version, now the app try to create new db but can't create and change modify on Database.

the Solution is :

JUST Change `DATABASE_VERSION`

the app forced to create new DataBase

GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

Just update the DATABASE_VERSION in your dbHelper class.